# Getting values from array one by one and writing some text according to array length to them javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem with getting results from this functon, estimated is #
11 years(let), and 10 days(dnů) OR if there in no years  output should only be 10 days, in case of years, months and days, it should be 10 years, 3 months and 4 days...here is my code

```
    function getAge(date_1, date_2)
    {
        var date2_UTC = new Date(Date.UTC(date_2.getUTCFullYear(), date_2.getUTCMonth(), date_2.getUTCDate()));
        var date1_UTC = new Date(Date.UTC(date_1.getUTCFullYear(), date_1.getUTCMonth(), date_1.getUTCDate()));


        var yAppendix, mAppendix, dAppendix;

        var days = date2_UTC.getDate() - date1_UTC.getDate();
        if (days < 0)
        {

            date2_UTC.setMonth(date2_UTC.getMonth() - 1);
            days += DaysInMonth(date2_UTC);
        }

        var months = date2_UTC.getMonth() - date1_UTC.getMonth();
        if (months < 0)
        {
            date2_UTC.setFullYear(date2_UTC.getFullYear() - 1);
            months += 12;
        }

        var years = date2_UTC.getFullYear() - date1_UTC.getFullYear();

        if (years > 5) yAppendix = " let";
        else if(years <= 4 && years >= 2) yAppendix = " roky";
        else yAppendix = " rok";
        if (months > 5) mAppendix = " měsíců";
        else if(months <= 4 && months >= 2) mAppendix = " měsíce";
        else mAppendix = " měsíc";
        if (days > 5) dAppendix = " dnů";
        else if(days <= 4 && days >= 2) dAppendix = " dny";
        else dAppendix = " den";
        var array = [];
        var echo;
        if(years == 0){} else  array.contact = years + yAppendix;
        if(months == 0){} else array.contact =  months + mAppendix;
        if(days == 0){} else array.contact = days + dAppendix;

            if(array.length = 1)  echo = array[0];
            else if(array.length = 2) echo = array[0] + " a " + array[1];
            else echo = array[0]+ ", " +array[1] + " a " + array[2];
            console.log(array);



        return  echo;
    }


    function DaysInMonth(date2_UTC)
    {
        var monthStart = new Date(date2_UTC.getFullYear(), date2_UTC.getMonth(), 1);
        var monthEnd = new Date(date2_UTC.getFullYear(), date2_UTC.getMonth() + 1, 1);
        var monthLength = (monthEnd - monthStart) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
        return monthLength;
    }
```

thanks for help

Comment: Could you show us some example input and the expected output?

Comment: input is from <input type="date"/> and output is only string like 10 years, 3 months and 1 day, but localized to my language